# Adding a ManyToManyField field to an existing model

Tags: python, django

I have a production model and I need to add the following field to it:

```
tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

The following is not picking up the change:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

And therefore, mymodel_tag table is not being created. I am using Postgres.

What are my options other than dropping the table and recreating it since the application is already on production use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[South](http://south.aeracode.org/) would definitely help:

> South is a tool to provide consistent, easy-to-use and database-agnostic migrations for Django applications.

Note that in Django 1.7 (currently in development stage) South is going to become a part of django ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)).

A good place to start is to go through the [tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) and [how to start using South with an existing database](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html) page.

Also see:

- [Django - syncdb doesn't create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016064/django-syncdb-doesnt-create-tables)
- [django-admin's syncdb does not check for missing many-to-many tables](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2229)
- [django adding a ManyToMany field/table to existing schema, related_name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989717/django-adding-a-manytomany-field-table-to-existing-schema-related-name-error)

Note that creating a many-to-many table manually may look like an easy solution/workaround in a short-perspective, but I'd consider switching to south anyway.

Hope that helps.